# Meteor ignore one css file

Tags: css, meteor

Seems like something that would have been asked/answered already but I cannot find anything related to this.

I have some CSS files that came with some packages. I want to not utilize a particular CSS file. Everything else in the package is great, but I'm having to use a lot of specificity to override the default styles it launches with, and it just seems hacky to override instead of remove.

I also don't want to just delete the file because I will likely want to update this package as new versions are released.

Is there some `Meteor.ignore('thatCssFile.css')` method of doing this?

Comment: Your best bet would probably be forking the package and making an unstyled version of it.

Comment: As of Meteor v1.5.2.1, you can now use `.meteorignore` in any directory. This could do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to fork this package on github and clone it (`git clone https://github.com/author/package.git package-clone`) as a local package of your app (in `my-app/packages/`).

Then you can edit the `package.js` file of the cloned package and simply comment the `api.addFiles` directive where the problematic CSS is added.

Synchronizing with the package maintainer would be only a matter of `git pull`ing the latest commits from the source repo.

You'll need to `meteor remove author:package` first and then add your local clone using `meteor add package-clone`.

Comment: Sounds like a solution, but I'm going to hold out for a minute for a simpler one. +1 for sure though.

Comment: At the moment this is you only option.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is correct, unless the cloned repo uses git submodules, in which case you must do:

```
git clone git://github.com/foo/bar.git
cd bar
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a bit late but another solution would be to use the [meteor-postcss](https://github.com/juliancwirko/meteor-postcss) package and configure the `excludedPackages` option.